# Why does a Gem provide ~> AND => in RubyGems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

The gem for bcrypt at https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt/versions/3.1.11

shows this usage

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
```

Why have the two versions of the pessimistic operator ?

We normally use just one version for other gems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>= 3.1.11` is an “optimistic” version constraint. It’s saying that all changes from `3.1.11` on will work, but for version `4.0.0` this will not be true.

`~> 3.1` is “pessimistic”. This explicitly excludes the version that might break your code. It is basically saying `>= 3.1` and `< 4.0`. But if you had `~> 3.1.1`, it will be equal to `>= 3.1.1` but less than `3.2`

If you want to allow use of newer backwards-compatible versions but need a specific bug fix you can use a compound requirement like `'~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'`  This is detailed at http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint *If you want to allow use of newer backwards-compatible versions but need a specific bug fix you can use a compound requirement such as... `'~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1'`*

Answer (score 3):

`'~> 3.1'` means the required version can be `3.1.x` or `3.2.x` or `3.3.x` or ..., but never to reach `4.0`.

The meaning of `'>= 3.1.11'` is quite clear.

So put them together, it means the version can be `3.x.y` where `x >= 2` or `x = 1 and y >= 11`.

Maybe this notation is more clear:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '>= 3.1.11', '< 4'
```